# Remove Avro type keys from JSON message format

Tags: python, avro, fastavro

I'm trying to create a script to deserialize some Avro messages that comes from Kafka.

The messages have a format like:

```
{
  "value": {
    "value1": {
      "string": "AAAA"
    }
  }
}
```

and I need it to be something like that

```
{
  "value": {
    "value1":  "AAAA"
  }
}
```

Basically, delete that string.

I have schemas for both of them.

I need to move from the message that is serialized with a schema to a message that is deserialized with another schema.

I tried to do something with python avro/fastavro, but I didn't succed.

I can not just delete that and format because the Avro that I need to reformat are much more complex. So, I need something that will reformat these avros based on my schemas.

Comment: Please clarify why you "need" the second format. You might get deserializer errors if the second object is read by a union schema. You're not just "deleting a string", you're changing a JSON object structure into a string, so depending on the parsing logic, that may not be expected. You "tried to do something"? Please clarify this too

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from the question if you are trying to convert between schemas or just remove that `string` hint. If you are just trying to remove the hint, you can do this:

```py
from fastavro import json_reader, json_writer

schema = {...}

with open('some-file', 'r') as fo:
    avro_reader = json_reader(fo, schema)
    records = [record for record in avro_reader]

with open('some-other-file', 'w') as out:
    json_writer(out, schema, records, write_union_type=False)
```